# Error on Grade: Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found

Tags: android, gradle

I need update an app after two years. But I got this message after the build:

> Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found.
>   Open File

Maybe I'm doing some wrong about the configuation of the gradle.

Here is my file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.xxx.xxxxx"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 28
            versionCode = 13
            versionName = "2.1.2"
            multiDexEnabled = true
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    android.dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "obfuscation-android-jni"
        platformVersion = "15"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.github.coyarzun89:fabtransitionactivity:0.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't know what I should do to fix this. I hope you could help me.

Comment: that should be `com.android.application` ?

Comment: @AliAhmed yes! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```